# Cortisol and inflammation

Tags: stress

Cortisol is released under stressful condition. It is known to have anti-inflammatory role. In fact it is used as potent anti-inflammatory drug also.

Though stressful conditions are unwanted and unfavorable, the body's response to such conditions by releasing cortisol, seems to be beneficial only.

If so, why cortisol is considered as undesirable and dangerous?